# Biometric face id at Istanbul airport

Tags: istanbul, turkish-airlines, star-alliance

Is there a biometric ( face id) based system at Istanbul airport? I know that Star alliance has similar systems at Frankfurt and Zurich  ( I had to enrol for those via the Lufthansa app) and I recall something similar was in progress at Istanbul via Turkish airlines.

However I cannot find any information about how to enrol for it.

Anyone know how it works?